# How to implement 'sort by popularity' in AWS CloudSearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

We have a requirement to implement 'Sort by popularity' in AWS CloudSearch. I didn't find any option. Please share your input if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation about sorting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/sorting-results.html) gives the example of how you can use an expression in your sort order - so you could have a field on each record in your index which was the "popularity" (the documentation talks about 'rank' - e.g. 1 for the most popular, 2 for the second most popular, etc) then incorporate that into your sort order somehow, combined with the relevancy `_score` by some kind of weighting.